# Template Literals from external file

Tags: javascript

I'd like to pass some variables into an html file I have and then send them via email. Most of that isn't very relevant to the issue so I'm going to go with a basic example.

Basic Template Literals work like so:

```
myLink = "google.com"
myID = "testID"
template = `Please visit ${myLink}/${myID} and let them know that ${myID} sent you.`
```

This would make template return:

> Please visit google.com/testID and let them know that testID sent you.

I've now copied the template code into an external file and am using `fs.readFileSync` to read the file into a variable. The problem is that it isn't actually evaluating the `${myLink}` and `${myID}` values after the file has been read. Is there anyway to accomplish this? If this is not possible with Template Literals can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: A template literal is JS code. If you are simply reading a file then that would be reading it as text, not as code to be run. You could do a regex-based `.replace()` on the string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't want to read the file, firstly that will read it as a string, and secondly there are better ways of dealing with JS modules.

What you want is to export the temple string as a function from one file and import it into the other.

File 1:

```
module.exports = (myLink, myID) => `Please visit ${myLink}/${myID} and let them know that ${myID} sent you.`
```

File 2:

```
const createString = require('./file1');
console.log(createString('google.com', 'testID'));
```

Comment: useful, but not an answer to the question

Comment: @ThomasW how doesn't it answer the question? My answer solves OP's problem of importing a string literal from an external file in the only way that that is doable

Answer (score 29):

I know eval is not much liked but this seems to be the only solution to your question.

```
eval("`"+str+"`");
```

Comment: Get's my vote. Regardless whether liked or not. That's the only way of doing what the OP asked.

Comment: Yep, eval is totally ok in some rare situations. That's what it's for. I might recommend escaping backticks in str, though.

Comment: This solution has the advantage for HTML templates, if you don;t want to use underscore or similar engines. The file doesn't contain is not a big JavaScript literal, but a usual HTML markup. Editors will highlight the syntax nicely.

Comment: Would be nice to see this elaborated a little more. I, for one, don't see how variables would be passed, for which I'm not sure this is actually answering the OP's question.

Comment: @benomatis `eval` would try to evaluate the template string using variable defined when it is called. So if the string looks like `"test ${blah} test"` and you just call `eval`, you'll get an error "ReferenceError: blah is not defined". If you then define `blah` as `let blah = "asd"`, calling `eval` will work and return a string `"test asd test"`

Comment: @ThierryJ. sorry, that didn't make it a whole lot clearer :) btw, wouldn't ```eval("`${str}`");``` (removed inner double-quotes and plus sign) or `eval(str)` do the same thing...?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small script that can do this without eval

```
let externalStringLiterals = async (string, correspondingStrings) => new Promise((finish) => {
    let templateString = string
    let templates = string.match(/\{.}/g)
    templates.forEach((str,index) => {
        templateString = templateString.replace(str,correspondingStrings[index])
        index >= templates.length-1 ? finish(templateString) : ''
    })
})
```

You can find it's documentation here too >> https://gist.github.com/netha145/abb2705cbad0e5fd7b41114aaa28bfd7

How It works?
It uses regex to find {number goes here} based on a number (Kinda similar to C# string literals).

Though you need to escape user input for security reasons and to not have bugs.